# Div slide back up not working

Tags: jquery, html, click, slide

When a user clicks a button...a div slides down...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#friend_requests_container").click(function(){
        $("#friend_requests").slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

However, what I want to do is when the user clicks anywhere else on the page, the div slides back up EXCEPT if they click on the button to reveal the div.

What i tried was this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#friend_requests_container").click(function(){
        $("#friend_requests").slideDown(500);
    }, function(){
        $("#friend_requests").fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

but that didnt seem to work...
Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `two` events one on `friend_requests_container` click and other on `document` click, When friend_requests_container is click the event is `propagated` to `document click` as well so you need to use `stopPropagation()`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/mwasc/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#friend_requests_container").click(function(event){     
        $("#friend_requests").slideDown(500);
                 event.stopPropagation();             
    });

    $(document).click(function(event){
        $("#friend_requests").slideUp(500);
         event.stopPropagation();      
    });   
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an event in the document and check the id of the clicked element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#friend_requests_container").click(function(){
        $("#friend_requests").slideDown(500);
    });

    $(document).click(function(e){
        if(e.target.id !== "friend_requests_container") {
           $("#friend_requests").slideUp(500);
        }
    });
});
```